# How to track changes of specific arrays of input fields and submit onChange in React-hook-form ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am able to track all input changes by using the watch() function in RHF and call API based on those changes. However, this method applies to all input fields that are not required to call API. So whenever user type in anything, it will also call the api by any character they type in which will make the server crashes.

Here is my code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((data, { name }) => {
      if (name === "includePA") {
        const singleValue = getValues("includePA");
        setChecked(singleValue);
        {
          singleValue == false
            ? setValue("premiumPA", 0)
            : setValue("premiumPA", 10000000);
        }
      }
      let timer;
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)();
      }, 500);
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [handleSubmit, watch]);
```

I tried to add unregister() but it doesn't work. Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [doc](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch/), you can create a watch for a specific field and use the useEffect hook to listen for any changes to that field to call api.

`const watchNameOnly = watch("name")`

Working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-watch-v7-forked-28hjvm?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: This only works for 1 field. I want to watch an array of fields.

Comment: @thaonguyen Okay, I understand. I believe you simply need to use an if-else logic to call the API if necessary. I have updated my demo accordingly.

Comment: @thaonguyen Can you mark the answer as done so that no one else tries to re-answer it?